# More than just friendly urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, friendly-url, codeigniter-routing

Here Some Urls that a gathered, and i wondered, How to use Codeigniter to active such result, and what are they called?

1. exemple.com/movies/action/some-title-that-i-want-to-implement/ (brings a post)
2. exemple.com/movie-name/some-title-that-i-want-to-implement/ (brings a specificity post)
3. exemple.com/movie-name (brings all the movie posts)
4. exemple.com/comic-con/movies/some-title-that-i-want-to-implement/ (brings a post)
5. exemple.com/comic-con/comics/some-title-that-i-want-to-implement/ (brings a post)
6. exemple.com/some-title-that-i-want-to-implement/ (brings a post)
7. exemple.com/2013/7/26/4558760/some-title-that-i-want-to-implement/ (brings a post)

The big question is how do you organize and think your application to have a similar result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use Codeigniter to active such result? Juat play with these:

1. `_remap()` function in your controller
2. [URI Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)
3. Routes config.

Example:

> exemple.com/movies/action/some-title-that-i-want-to-implement/ (brings
>   a post)

Let say your default controller is `home`; then :

config/routes.php:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/$1'
```

controller/home.php

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        //do somthing
    }

    public function _remap()
    {
       //play with uri segment here, i.e:
       if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'movies')
       {
         //take 'movies' as parameter and use it
       }
       else
       {
        //you can be more creative than me
       }
    }
}
```

what are they called? I am not sure, I guess 'Virtual URI Mapping'.

how do you organize and think your application to have a similar result?
There is no something special.